# What is the textual source of the 4 infinitudes and the 6 coolnesses?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon

If I remember this right I heard about the 4 infinitudes and the 6 coolnesses on podcasts. Not sure if I'm getting the names right and/or representing these properly. The question is, I'm looking for the textual source of these two lists in the scriptures.

4 infinitudes:

- mind of a buddha
- the mind in Jahna
- space
- world systems

6 coolnesses:

- When the mind needs to be restrained you restrain it
- When your mind needs to be exerted you exert it
- When it needs to be encouraged to encourage it
- When you should develop equanimity you develop the quality of equanimity
- When there’s resolve on the mark of freedom you reserve on that mark
- Delighting in freedom

Answer (score 3):

"There are these four unconjecturables that are not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about them. Which four?

"The Buddha-range of the Buddhas[1] is an unconjecturable that is not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about it.

"The jhana-range of a person in jhana...[2]

"The [precise working out of the] results of kamma...

"Conjecture about [the origin, etc., of] the world is an unconjecturable that is not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about it.

"These are the four unconjecturables that are not to be conjectured about, that would bring madness & vexation to anyone who conjectured about them."
https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.077.than.html

Comment: i want to say what i asked about differs from these "unconjecturables" or "imponderables" right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the unconjecturables are likely the same as what I was naming the “infinitudes.”

As for the 6 coolnesses:

aṅguttara nikāya
6. book of the sixes
85. Cooled

https://suttacentral.net/an6.85/en/thanissaro

“A monk endowed with six qualities is incapable of realizing the unexcelled cooled state. Which six? There is the case where a monk doesn’t rein in his mind when it should be reined in. He doesn’t exert his mind when it should be exerted. He doesn’t gladden his mind when it should be gladdened. He doesn’t watch over his mind when it should be watched over. He is intent on what is lowly. And he delights in self-identity. A monk endowed with these six qualities is incapable of realizing the unexcelled cooled state.

“A monk endowed with six qualities is capable of realizing the unexcelled cooled state. Which six? There is the case where a monk reins in his mind when it should be reined in. He exerts his mind when it should be exerted. He gladdens his mind when it should be gladdened. He watches over his mind when it should be watched over. He is intent on what is exquisite. And he delights in Unbinding. A monk endowed with these six qualities is capable of realizing the unexcelled cooled state.”